# Why don't import models in all page django

Tags: python, django

```
from models import *


def info(request):
    yasin = "teksaas"
    if check_key(request):
        api = get_api(request)
        user = api.me()
        userid = user.id
        accounts=accounts.objects.filter(twitterid=userid)
        if accounts == 1:
            return render_to_response('twitter_auth/info.html', locals())
        else:

            registeracc=accounts(twitterid=412313,others='Hello im jsaon walker what your problem i cant unt')
            registeracc.save()
            return render_to_response('twitter_auth/info.html', locals()) 
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('main'))


Error : local variable 'accounts' referenced before assignment
```

**İf i change this code it's working but i dont want multiple import models**

```
def info(request):
    yasin = "teksaas"
    if check_key(request):
                from models import *
        api = get_api(request)
        user = api.me()
        userid = user.id
        accounts=accounts.objects.filter(twitterid=userid)
        if accounts == 1:
            return render_to_response('twitter_auth/info.html', locals())
        else:
            from models import *
            registeracc=accounts(twitterid=412313,others='Hello im jsaon walker what your problem i cant unt')
            registeracc.save()
            return render_to_response('twitter_auth/info.html', locals()) 
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('main'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not name your variable like your class

```
accounts=accounts.objects.filter(twitterid=userid)
```

Try fix it and see if that can help

```
from models import *
def info(request):
    yasin = "teksaas"
    if check_key(request):
        api = get_api(request)
        user = api.me()
        userid = user.id
        acc=accounts.objects.filter(twitterid=userid)
        if acc:
            return render_to_response('twitter_auth/info.html', locals())
        else:

            registeracc=accounts(twitterid=412313,others='Hello im jsaon walker what your problem i cant unt')
            registeracc.save()
            return render_to_response('twitter_auth/info.html', locals()) 
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('main'))
```

Comment: According to [PEP-8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#class-names) class names should be written with an uppercase first letter. In short: sticking to the standard might help to avoid this mistake.